# How can I change the PickerStyle in SwiftUI like Embed in Form, but static and not scrollable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I would like to have a picker who is like involved in form{}. It should look like it's a navigation link. that problem is if I program it into a form{}, then it is scrollable and I do not want that. I want to have it static, Or one knows a solution how to make forms static and not scrollable.

Comment: You should add images and/or code

Comment: U see topside is the picker and bot side a self created "Picker" like navigationlink. the topside u can slide it up and down and this function i didnt want. i want it like the bot side, this is fixed on positing https://imgur.com/12QCu3U

Comment: I'm having the same scrolling problem on beta 6. To me, it looks like a bug. You could always report it to Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XCode 11 Beta 6**

@Daniel Ryan I have now programmed my own method, which works very well.

```
import SwiftUI

var AnArrays : [String] =  [  "eins", "zwei", "drei", "vier", "fünf"]

struct ContentView: View {
     @State var Gepickt : String = ""
     var body : some View {
          NavigationView{
               VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: AuswahlPick(gewählt: $Gepickt)) {
                         HStack {
                              Text("PickerMaSelf")
                                   .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                              Spacer()
                              Text(Gepickt.count > 0 ? Gepickt : "Pick One ?")  .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                              Image(systemName: "chevron.right")  .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                                   .padding(.trailing)
                         }
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}

struct AuswahlPick: View {
     @Binding var gewählt : String
     @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
     var body: some View {
          Form{
               ForEach(AnArrays, id: \.self){ x in
                    Button(action: {
                         self.gewählt = "\(x)"
                         self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                         Text("\(x)")
                              .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
     static var previews: some View {
          ContentView()
     }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the corresponding modifier:

`.pickerStyle()`

For example this code:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var strengths = ["Mild", "Medium", "Mature"]

    @State var selectedStrength = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedStrength, label: Text("Strength")) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< strengths.count) {
                            Text(self.strengths[$0]).tag($0)
                        }
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(.default)
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Select your cheese"))

        }
    }
}
```

It is like embedded in the form, but you can use `.pickerStyle(.wheel)` to make it look like the original picker inside the list.

But since you question is not clear enough, I think the **default** one is actually what is you are asking for.

Comment: Ya but this is, what I didn’t want! This is scrollbar. I don’t want this scroll Action.

Comment: I want a picker style like in Forms. My prob is, the form have inside a scroll function and this scroll function want to disable it.

Comment: Please add some image [using this site](https://imgur.com) and put the links in the question. I don't understand you actually.

Comment: U see topside is the picker and bot side a self created "Picker" like navigationlink.
the topside u can slide it up and down and this function i didnt want.
i want it like the bot side, this is fixed on positing https://imgur.com/12QCu3U

Comment: Why is the picker style modifier being applied to the section instead of the picker? What if there are multiple pickers in a section?